# JS Object Literals - How to access from outside an object?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, object-literal

I'm new to JavaScript and having troubles with accessing an object from outside.
My method fills an array with Objects before I want to access an property of this object.

```
Reservation = {
   objArr: [],                     // stores CalendarDates objects
   dates: ["test", "foo", "bar"],  // some test strings

   actionMethod: function() {
      Reservation.objArr[0] = new Reservation.CalendarDate.construct(Reservation.dates[0]);
      alert(Reservation.dates[0].testVariable);        // returns 'undefined'
   }
};

Reservation.CalendarDate = {
   testVariable: '',
   construct: function(testVariable) {
      Reservation.CalendarDate.testVariable = testVariable;
   }
};
```

How can I access the property (testVariable) from outside the object, which is stored in an array.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That ain't valid JS. You can't add properties to a object using `=`, like you're doing with `objArr` and `dates`.

Comment: `Reservation.CalendarDate.testVariable`

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with the `construct` method. That isn't how you define a constructor in JavaScript. Is that what you intended?

Comment: my mistake, I've edited my question. But the problem still exists.

Comment: possibly `alert(Reservation.dates[0].testVariable);` -> `alert(Reservation.objArr[0].testVariable);`  *and* `Reservation.CalendarDate.testVariable = testVariable;` -> `this.testVariable = testVariable;`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to accomplish something along these lines...

```js
    var Reservation = {
       objArr: [],                     // stores CalendarDates objects
       dates: ["test", "foo", "bar"],  // some test strings

       actionMethod: function() {
         var temp = new Reservation.CalendarDate(Reservation.dates[0]);
          Reservation.objArr[0] = temp;
          alert(Reservation.objArr[0].testVariable);
       }
      };

      Reservation.CalendarDate = function(testVariable) {
         this.testVariable = testVariable;
      };

      Reservation.actionMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish but this will do what you want:

```
Reservation = {
  objArr: [], // stores CalendarDates objects
  dates: ["test", "foo", "bar"], // some test strings

  actionMethod: function() {
    this.objArr[0] = new this.CalendarDate.construct(this.dates[0]);
    alert(this.objArr[0].testVariable); // returns 'test'
  },

  CalendarDate: {
    testVariable: '',
    construct: function(testVariable) {
      this.testVariable = testVariable;
    }
  }
};
```

That said, if you are trying to mimic classes in Javascript (I won't start a flamewar about why you shouldn't) you should read one of the many good articles/books out there on it. [Getify's free book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#class-functions) has some good info on this topic.